# Python get previous few elements if match checked element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have some structured data in a text file:

**Parse.txt**

```
name1
detail:
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
detail1:
dddddddd
detail2:
eeeeeeee
detail3:
ffffffff
detail4:
gggggggg
```

some of the detail4s do not have data and would be replaced by "-":

```
name2
detail:
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
detail1:
dddddddd
detail2:
eeeeeeee
detail3:
ffffffff
detail4:
-
```

**How do i parse the data to get the elements below detail1, detail2 and detail3 of only the data with empty detail4s?**

So far i have a partially working code but the problem is that it gets each item 40 times. Please help.

**Code:**

```
data = []
with open("parse.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        data.append(line)
det4li = []
finali= []

for elem,det4 in zip(data,data[1:]):
    if "detail4" in elem:
        det4li .append(det4)
        if "-" in det4:
            for elem1,det1,det2,det3 in zip(data,data[1:],data[3:],data[5:]):
                if "detail1:" in elem1:
                    finali.append(det1.strip() + "," + det2.strip() + "," + det3)
```

> > Current Output: 40 records of dddddddd,eeeeeeee,ffffffff
> >
> > Desired Output: dddddddd,eeeeeeee,ffffffff

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to look ahead. Look *behind*, by storing preceding data:

```
final = []
with open("parse.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    section = {}
    last_header = None
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('detail'):
            # detail line, record for later use
            last_header = line.rstrip(':')
        elif not last_header:
            # name line, store as such
            section['name'] = line
        else:
            section[last_header] = line
            if last_header == 'detail4':
                # section complete, process
                if line == '-':
                    # A section we want to keep
                    final.append(section)
                # reset section data
                section, last_header = {}, None
```

This has the added advantage that you now don't need to read the whole file into memory. If you turn this into a generator (by putting it into a function and replacing the `final.append(section)` line with `yield section`), you can even process those matching sections as you read the file without sacrificing readability.